# Class diagram examples for RPG (Role Playing Game)

Tags: class, project-planning, class-diagram

Does anyone know where I can find examples of class diagrams for RP game development? Something similar to [here](http://members.gamedev.net/emmanuel_deloget/images/text_rpg_rule_system.png) would be quite useful. I'm not looking for things I can slavishly copy, but just for different examples that diagram various solutions to the problems I'm discovering as I try and pencil down my own classes.

Comment: I love the one you linked to. I swear most of us programmers, especially the ones with ordinary day jobs, must only do RPGs for the cathartic experience of writing functions like `bool isLivingDead()`.

Comment: if (creature.isLivingDead() && hero.isSlayer()) hero.slay(creature);

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I know Emmanuel Deloget from GameDev.net but I'm not sure I would choose to use the hierarchy he's got there! Too much inheritance, not enough flexibility.

If I was writing a text-based RPG (as I have done in the past) it would look a bit like this (though I've no time to draw up a diagram for it, sadly):

- Creatures, Rooms, and Items derived
  from WorldEntity, with WorldEntity
  objects arranged in a Composite
  structure, so items can live within
  other items, carried by creatures,
  who exist within rooms. Implementing
  the Visitor pattern for WorldEntities
  might work well.
- CreatureType and ItemType classes
  which contain the 'class' data for
  individual Creature and Item
  instances, which refer back to their
  corresponding 'type' object. (eg. base
  hitpoints and stats in the former,
  current hitpoints and transient effects
  in the latter). I might implement these as
  prototypical lists of properties that get
  copied to Creature or Item instances when
  they are created. You can implement property
  inheritance via a 'parent' property so that
  a specific goblin Creature instance may relate to the 
  'warrior goblin' CreatureType, which contains a
  parent reference to the 'generic goblin' CreatureType. And so on.
- Exits that are owned by their Room, and are
  one way, and which detail the direction of
  travel, various conditions of passage, etc.
- Areas, that contain groups of rooms connected
  by some logical organisation.
- A Spawn class to dictate where Creature
  and Item instances are created (eg. which room,
  or at what coordinates), when they are created and
  with what frequency, and from
  which CreatureTypes and ItemTypes. You may have
  some logic in here to randomise things a bit.
- Spells, skills, abilities, etc.
  all derived from a base Action class
  or interface that specifies prerequisites
  (eg. current position, mana points, some
  degree of learning of a skill, etc). Normal
  commands and actions can go here too since they
  often have some sort of requirements too
  (eg. a 'sleep' command requires that you're not
  already sleeping.)
- A FutureEvent class which is essentially a
  callback that you push onto a priority queue
  to execute in the future. You can use these to
  schedule combat rounds, spell cool-down times,
  night/day cycles, whatever you like.
- A hash/map/dictionary of name->value pairs for
  player and item statistics. Not type-safe but
  you'll appreciate the flexibility later. In my
  experience making stats member variables is
  workable but inflexible, and having specialise
  'attribute' classes becomes a convoluted
  nightmare when debugging.
- A Modifier type which contains a stat name
  and a modifier value (eg. +10, +15%). These
  get added to your creatures as they are used
  (eg. through a spell effect, or by wielding
  an enchanted weapon) and get stripped off later
  by a timed FutureEvent or some other event such
  as a command being executed.
- Game-specific classes such as PlayerClass or
  PlayerRace, each of which describe a player's class
  (eg. warrior, wizard, thief) or race (human, elf,
  dwarf) and set starting stat values and limits,
  skill availability lists, special powers, etc.
- Basic player interface classes which will vary
  depending on your actual game type. You might
  have a rendering classes for a graphical game, or
  in a MUD you might have a Connection class
  reflecting the TCP connection to the player's client.
  Try to keep all game logic out of these.
- A scripting interface. Most of your commands, spells,
  and creature AI can be realised more quickly with
  a decent scripting interface and it keeps compile times
  down too. It also allows for some great in-game debugging
  and diagnostic capabilities.

That would be the basic high level structure I'd use.

Comment: That's the second fantastic answer you've provided for my game related questions. Thank you

Comment: If you were to use an MVC architecture for this game. What would the separation of the model, view and controller look like for this class structure?

Comment: @IntegrityFirst: I wouldn't use MVC so that's a question you'd have to answer yourself. But handling I/O (including graphics) depends entirely on the platform the game is being made for.

Answer (score 11):

You may want to consider a component entity system rather than a traditional inheritance hierarchy; they tend to be more flexible to certain types of change, make tool (e.g. world editor) development much easier, and present opportunities for parallelization that might not otherwise be obvious or easy.

Many modern game engines are moving away from the "monolithic class Object" (or class Entity, whatever) and toward a "bag of components" approach.

There are numerous books and articles around.  Generally:

- the [Game Programming Gems](http://www.gameprogramminggems.com/) series (apparently both volume 5 and 6 have component articles, and I think 2 might have had one as well)
- the [Game Developers Conference](http://gdconf.com/) website often has links to presentations from prior years, and is a goldmine for this sort of thing -- you can even usually buy the CDs/DVDs for former years cheaply (especially if you attend)
- [Gamasutra's feature article archives](http://www.gamasutra.com/php-bin/article_display.php) and the [Game Developer Magazine](http://www.gdmag.com/) backissues

Specifically (some noteworthy ones, google "component" and "entity" in various combinations for more):

- [Evolve Your Hierarchy](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/), Mick West
- [Entity Systems are the future of MMOG development](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/); also [part 2](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/11/11/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-2/) and [part 3](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/12/22/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-3/)
- [Introduction to Dungeon Siege Architecture](http://garage.gaspowered.com/?q=su_301) on the Gas Powered Games wiki
- [A Data-Driven Game Object System](http://scottbilas.com/games/dungeon-siege), Scott Bilas (GDC 2002)
- the [Nocturnal Initiative](http://nocturnal.insomniacgames.com/index.php/Main_Page), a openly-licensed collection of libraries and tools from Insomniac Games (they have one of the biggest tool efforts in the industry, from what I've seen)

Each of these articles links to a few more.

Try the kool-aid, you might like it.  =)

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard about the component driven design before, but it looks interesting.

Comment: @nemo: thanks for the note, it was working two days ago.  =(  I've put his new blog link in, but it doesn't appear to have the presentation, and a note that you can still get to the presentation using google's cache.

Answer (score 5):

```
<tongue_in_cheek_mode_because_it_is_friday>
```

Just to start:

```
          ----------------                    --------------
          |   Creature   |                    |  Item      |
          |--------------|                    |------------|
          | Name         |                    | Name       |
          | Hp           |                    | Value      |
          | Abilities    |--------------------| Weight     |
          |--------------|                    --------------
          | Attack       |
          ----------------
                 ^
                 |
        ----------------------
        |                    |
----------------    ----------------
|  Hero        |    |  Monster     |
|--------------|    |--------------|
| Level        |    |              |
|--------------|    |--------------|
| KillMonster  |    | AttackAndDie |
| GrabTreasure |    | DropTreasure |
----------------    ----------------

</tongue_in_cheek_mode_because_it_is_friday>
```

Comment: It does look startlingly familiar to my own design I have to admit :)

Comment: Lol, it totally depends on the system you want to implement. It can be simple, but as usual, rpg systems are extremely complex. But then again, the game is not finished until you found the hackmaster+12 ;-).

Comment: I think my main problem is that I'm not sure exactly what 'gazebo' is supposed to inherit...

Comment: Great stuff and startlingly close  to most RPG code I've seen ;)

Comment: two types of RPGs out there - one type mimics the simplicity of paper and pencil RPGs, and the other type uses the benefit of the computer doing all the rolling to make some complex monstrosity which implemented in P&P the die rolling would mimic the sound of hail.

Comment: Call me old fashioned, but I still prefer tabletop rpg ;-).

Comment: In a tabletop RPG, you can do something the designer never thought of.  If you get that with a computer RPG, it won't work as you might expect.  I see no way to change that in the near future.

Comment: @Steerpike:  Obviously, Gazebo should inherit from ReallyScaryThingThatWakesUpAndEatsYou.

Answer (score 4):

How about something of the sort : 

[alt text http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/4886/classwo0.png](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/4886/classwo0.png)

Here are some other diagrams:

- http://www.russelldare.net/media/2dgame/uml.jpg
- http://dirkkok.files.wordpress.com/2007/12/domainmodel1.jpg?w=505&h=573
- http://members.gamedev.net/emmanuel_deloget/images/text_rpg_rule_system.png
- http://theworldofdan.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/classdiagram1.jpg
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/SpaceInvaders06292005005618AM/Images/SpaceInvadersUML.jpg
- http://blog.xlandersoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/tankrushuml.png

Comment: 3 Mains and 3 GameEngineDatas? I believe some refactoring is in order.

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse...I posted these images just to get the gist of how to start in building such a UML

Answer (score 4):

A [very different approach](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html) by Steve Yegge.

Comment: Yeah, the key/value concept is like another version of Greenspun's 10th Rule: almost every system ends up with it somewhere. I suggest using it for character and item properties, including the inheritance model that Steve and others talk about.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [JADE's Javadoc](http://www.adom.de/jade/javadoc-jade-007/index.html) for a good overview of a complex game :)

Comment: I've worked on large, professional, AAA games with a simpler class structure.

Answer (score 1):

Be bold, your game shouldn't be a clone of hack and slash nonsense.
Your actors should be able to switch sides, take their own initiative 
enlist other actors, etc.  Otherwise, whats the point?

```
   +-----------------------------+
   V                             |
[Actor] ------- [Allegiance] ----+
 - risk comfort    - weight
 - temerity
```

Comment: That's much further down the line. No matter what you do, you're still going to need a system like the ones above to classify all of these actors and the required AI.